# Get VK user avatar in Swift

Tags: swift, vk, vk-sdk

I know how to get user email address in vkSdkAccessAuthorizationFinishedWithResult method. How can I get his avatar image and other profile info?

I assume that i need to use VKRequest for this.
Unfortunately i found no swift documentation for VK iOS SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i finally found solution - you need to add this code inside vkSdkAccessAuthorizationFinishedWithResult method

```
let request:VKRequest = VKRequest(method: "users.get", andParameters: ["fields":"photo_50", "bdate"], andHttpMethod: "GET" )

request.executeWithResultBlock({ response in
       print(response.json)
    }, errorBlock: {
        (error) -> Void in
        print("error")

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Class `VKAccessToken` contains `localUser` property. You can access user profile info (including name, id) like this:

```
VKSdk.accessToken().localUser
```

`VKUser` class has fields like `photo_max`, `photo_50`, ... `photo_max_orig` which contain urls for images.

Comment: var user  = VKSdk.accessToken().localUser.first_name
print(user)
this code breaks "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: @moonvader VKSdk.accessToken().localUser is nil if VK app is not installed.